# Whatsapp Web Selenium with C# send message without reloads the web

Tags: whatsapp

I have created one project for automating Whatsapp message using web Whatsapp with selenium in C# code. It works perfectly fine but every time the URL is loaded for new message, how can I stop reloading the page and send message?

Below is my code and I have one for loop for all my numbers and I am calling SendMessage method for every numbers

```
private void SendMessage(string number, string message)
{
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 

  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + number + "&text=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(message));

  driver.FindElement(By.Id("action-button")).Click(); 

  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button._2lkdt>span")).Click();
}
```

I need like this video: https://youtu.be/vzxyhPPEp9w?t=100

Thanks